# AngularJS failing to load module

Tags: angularjs

I have come across a lot of similar issues here on SF and did everything as expected. Yet, I can't seem to get this simple Angular app working. Console throws up this exception

```
angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

AngularJS site docs gave some suggestions which I followed. Yet, I still get that same exception. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dead Simple Proj</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/css/styles.css">
  <script scr="app\app.js"></script>
  <script src="app\lib\angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="GreetingController">
    {{ greeting }}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have this in the App.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
});
```

I double checked file paths and other possibly obvious mistakes, but no joy. 
I am definitely missing out something here? Thanks.

Comment: First angular library file should load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paths referencing the libraries and the app.js are wrong and in the wrong order . You should load the angular reference first and then the relative js referencing the module.

Change

**From**

```
 <script scr="app\app.js"></script>
 <script src="app\lib\angular.min.js"></script>
```

**To**

```
  <script src="app/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script scr="app/app.js"></script>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dead Simple Proj</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/css/styles.css">
   <script type=" text/javascript " src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js "></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="GreetingController">
    {{ greeting }}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Sajee, I did and still get the same exception.

Comment: @BabaganaZannah  there is no issue with the answer, check if your references are loading . did you check the demo?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you added your angular files properly. I made a plunker out of your  code and it worked. you can cross check with my code.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body  ng-controller="GreetingController">
    <h1>Hello {{greeting}}!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Brilliant. It worked. I replaced my html head with yours. Do you know why is that?

Comment: That means your angular file didn't load properly. Are u sure linked the angular files properly?

Comment: @BabaganaZannah there is nothing different in this answer!

Comment: yes i do agree that the previous answer provided by @Sajeetharan is the better answer to the question as i dont think you should resort to using the cdn just because the file isnt referenced properly. thanks.